# Enter digit instead of checkmark in box with Preview

Tags: macos, preview

I am using Preview to edit a PDF document. How do enter a digit instead of a tick or a cross (checkmark) in a box using the Preview app on macOS?

Answer (score 1):

From the Annotate toolbar (shown by clicking the pen icon), choose the Text tool. This inserts a text box into the document, which you can type characters in and reposition where you would like the characters to appear in the document.

[image]

The default tool, text selection (highlighted blue on the left of the above screenshot) will automatically enter a check mark in a box it determines to be a checkbox. You need to manually add text boxes where you wish text to appear if the assumption by Preview is incorrect.